# What is the recommended (official) way to backup apple books (iBook) purchases?

Tags: backup, books

What is the recommended way to make a backup of all the books I have purchased with Apple books (formerly known as iBooks), preferably using macOS?

Or may there is even an official way recommended by Apple?

Comment: Do you just want to backup the folder where your iBooks purchases are downloaded to on your Mac, or are you aiming to convert them to a format you can still read should the iBooks service cease to exist?

Comment: I would like to explicitly get the files and backup (and restore) just them. Since it is ePub (isn’t it?) I would not have to convert them to be able to read them somewhere else. I just need another ePub reader (right?).

Answer (score 1):

Apple’s recommended method for any local  backups is Time Machine. While other options exist, none of them match your combined wishes in question.

Answer (score -2):

When you select the options for the book (`...`), you can `Share PDF` and simply e-mail it, save to files, etc.

Comment: Do I have to do this for each and every book manually? Also I'd prefer to do it on macOS.

Comment: PDF can’t substitute for books that have more than just text in them., and probably is not permitted for paid books that have drm.